# Recover closed exchange outlook emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I used to have a exchange server setup in my outlook. But recently due to a hardware failure my exchange server is corrupted and down, I cannot recover the changes server so I need to completely remove it and setup new server.

But I want to recover my old email, I have all those emails in my outlook. Outlook is running and showing my old emails but it is not connecting to the exchange server.

I tried to take a PST backup as mentioned in this link: http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-export-an-outlook-2010-pst-file-exchange-2010 but that is also not working and says Outlook mut be connected to exchange to perform this action.

Please advise some way to copy my emails in PST files, or some other way to get those as PST backup so that I can restore in new exchange when setup.

Comment: Your options are limited.  You won't be able to copy the emails to a local storage device without being able to actually copy the actual email instead of what is simply a cache of the content.  To put it bluntly you are out of luck.

Comment: There are .ost to .ost converter programs out there. They worked for outlook 2003 (untested for 2010) but where not free. It might be worth looking for recent versions of a similar program.

Alternatively, install a new exchange server and recover the mailstore from backups.

Comment: Can this solution work: http://helpdesk.princeton.edu/kb/display.plx?ID=9699 I think Yes?

Comment: It can work **if** you have a working exchange server. However the OP stated that this does not work when outlook cannot connect to the exchange server. (Those personal folders are stored in a .pst file).